# Return the number of elements smaller than 3.0 in an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am making a function that returns the number of elements smaller than 3.0 in an array.

I am trying to use the function prototype `int smaller_than_three(int *x, int size);` where `x` is a pointer to the first element of the array, and `size` is the size of the array.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int smaller_than_three(int *x, int size);     

int main()
{
    smaller_than_three(0,10);
    return 0;
}


int smaller_than_three(int *x, int size)
{
    int array[size][size];
    *x = &array[size][0];

    int i;
    int j=0;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        if (array[size][i] < 3.0) {
            j = j+1;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

I'm not sure where the problems lie in my `*x` and implementing my array.

Comment: What goes wrong? What's the problem you're asking us to solve?

Comment: If `smaller_than_three` is supposed to take a pointer to the first element of an array, you're going to need to pass it a pointer to the first element of an array rather than passing it 0, and you're going to need to go through that array rather than declaring another one in `smaller_than_three`.

Comment: I think you meant to pass the array as the first argument, but right now you are passing `0`, which is a null pointer.

Comment: so you mean defining an array and passing it as an argument? I am confused..?

Comment: Yes, start with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you take into account that array variables are (essentially) pointers, and are always pointers when passed as function parameters, and pointers can be treated as an array, then your code simply becomes this:

```
int smaller_than_three(int* list, int size)
{
    int found = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (list[index] < 3)
           found++;
    }

    return found;
}

int main()
{
    int list[] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    int found = smaller_than_three(list, 10);
    printf("%d\n", found); // prints "2"
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you are comparing elements in an integer list with "3.0" which is a floating point value. This causes a minor overhead and introduces floating point where it's likely not needed. You can optionally change your list array to be of type "double" or "float" if you need floating point comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

you're setting the `int*` to an uninitialized array:

```
int array[size][size];
*x = &array[size][0];
```

you probably wanted to receive the pointer to the array as a function parameter and not overwrite it. As it is it doesn't make much sense. Remove those two lines, and pass a pointer to an actual array to the function.